# Unix Shell -- Issue a command that changes permissions for all files and directories excluding one

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to recursively change permissions for all directories and files within my current working directory but while excluding one of the directories.

I have tried a bunch of variations of the following command and can't get it quite right

find . -type d ! -name directoryName -exec chmod -R 700 {} +

Comment: Have you tried it with the `-prune` option?

Comment: lol hm wasn't aware of the --exclude= option, I am pretty new to the shell but that seems like a pretty obvious solution. I'll try it

Comment: Brain was stuck in `rsync` mode...

Comment: prune doesn't seem to be working. Heres what i tried:  [code] find . -type d -prune -o -name dirName -exec chmod -R 700 {} + [/code]

Comment: Well, I though you would have found the answer below. You can use your *original* command, just get rid of the `-R` and it will exclude the directory you specify in `! -name directoryName`. What is happening now with `-R` is regardless of the `! -name` exclusion, you still change the mode of all directories (because when operating on the *parent* of `directoryName`, the `chmod` is being applied to it, **and all its children...** `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The `-R` argument to `chmod` tells it to work recursively. Since you're enumerating all the objects individually you should not use this option.

Answer (score 0):

This did it. Thank you guys for the suggestions.

```
find . ! -name website ! -path "./website/*" -exec chmod 700 {} +
```